# form automation 12 digit number extracting with decimal

Tags: python, selenium, xlrd

I'm working on a form automation script in python. It extracts the data from a excel file and fills out in a online form. The problem I'm facing is with a 12-digit number in a column in excel file data. The number seems fine the excel file by using custom setting for it but when the python script extracts the data it appears as a hexadecimal number. I've tried using many things but nothing really seems to work. I'm using xlrd.

My current script

```
stradh = str(sheet.cell(row,col).value) 
browser.find_element_by_id('number').send_keys(stradh)
```

Number in excel file:

```
357507103697
```

Number when extracting from python script:

```
3.57507103697e+11
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the decimal module and convert no from scientific no

```
from xlrd import *
import decimal 

workbook = open_workbook('temp.xlsx')

sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)

value = sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

print decimal.Decimal(value)
```

Comment: This is working when I'm printing the value but when I'm trying to pass the value it's showing the error 'object of type 'Decimal' has no len()'

Comment: Using str() solves my problem. Thanks. Your solution was a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using longint.Try, `long(sheet.cell(row,col).value)`. I hope this helps.If you need string then you can use str on long.